# Locating element in DOM for automated test case

Tags: javascript, ruby, selenium, automation, watir

To locate element in DOM, I am using the following path:

```
 div[id^=customswindow-][id$=-body]>div>div:nth-child(3)>div>div>div>div>div>div>div>div>div>div>div>div>input
```

Is there a way to shrink sequence of divs? **div>div>div>div>div>div>div>div>div>div>div>div>**

Comment: depends on page structure most notably any classes or ID's along that path. If you are writing that manually I'm sure you could clean it up a lot. I have written things like that but programmatically walking up the dom to create them and only because of not being in charge of the structure

Comment: Share HTML code sample for the same

Comment: Can you share your html sample?

Comment: One goal of Watir is to make it so that you don't need to use XPath to locate your elements. If the element you are looking for is an input, you shouldn't need to drill down that much to find it. Depending on what inputs you have on the page, how close does this get you? `browser.div(id: /^customswindow-/).input`

Comment: @titusfortner I think a logical `css` or `xpath` does the same.

Comment: please share the html sample

Comment: Does the same as what? Obviously there are tons of ways of locating elements. I'm saying Watir specifically tries to make it such that users can avoid that kind of ugliness/insanity with more easy to read approaches. Using Watir while ignoring what it is good at is suboptimal.

Comment: @titusfortner Definitely when I'm speaking about `xpath` & `css` I mean Selenium Locators business. I wonder in which perspective did you find such ugliness/insanity here. Watir as I understand is just a wrapper against diverse waits

Comment: Then you really misunderstand what Watir is @DebanjanB

Comment: @Eng80lvl  please edit your question to include a sample of the HTML around the element you wish to identify.

Comment: downvoted due to lack of response from original poster

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is no Best Practices defined when solving a task/problem. Having said that, the `cssSelector` which you have used is based on it's `Absolute Path`. `cssSelector` and `xpath` based on `Absolute Path` tends to be brittle. Hence we need to construct `Logical Path`.

So inspite of the `cssSelector` you have used as :

```
div[id^=customswindow-][id$=-body]>div>div:nth-child(3)>div>div>div>div>div>div>div>div>div>div>div>div>input
```

I would suggest to start looking only at the `<input>` tags with its attributes. You can use any of the approaches as mentioned below :

```
//using id and other attribute
input#id[attribute=value]

//using classname and other attribute
input.classname[attribute=value]

//using id, classname and other attribute
input#id.classname[attribute=value]

//using three different attributes
input[attribute1=value][attribute2=value][attribute3=value]
```